# How can I catch the error when the wrong SMS code is entered in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using phone authentication in Firebase platform. Actually I solved this problem with the below code but Firebase give me another error similar laters.

I am trying to 2 options; one of them is using catch(e), another one is using FirebaseAuthException catch (me) but I always get same error.

```
  signin() async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: code);
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      print("successful");
    } catch (e) {
      print("not successful");
    }    
  }
```

> Exception has occurred.
> PlatformException (PlatformException(invalid-verification-code, The SMS verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code SMS and be sure to use the verification code provided by the user., {code: invalid-verification-code, message: The SMS verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code SMS and be sure to use the verification code provided by the user., nativeErrorMessage: The SMS verification code used to create the phone auth credential is invalid. Please resend the verification code SMS and be sure to use the verification code provided by the user., nativeErrorCode: 17044, additionalData: {}}))

Answer (score 3):

you can filter error by `FirebaseAuthException` code;

```
signin() async {
  final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
    verificationId: verificationId,
    smsCode: code,
  );
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    print("successful");
  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'invalid-verification-code') {
      onWrongCode();
    }
    onOtherError(e);
  } catch (e) {
    onOtherError(e);
  }
}
```